# how do i interpret the result of polyserial correlation in r?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, categorical-data, r-corrplot

I used `polyserial()` function to correlate categorical and continuous variables. This is my R code and results.

```
polyserial(segdata$IDT000003, segdata$CA0000801,ML = FALSE, std.err = FALSE)
[1] 0.2017285
polyserial(segdata$IDT000003, segdata$CA0000801,ML = TRUE, std.err = FALSE)
[1] 0.2581445
polyserial(segdata$IDT000003, segdata$CA0000801,ML = FALSE, std.err = TRUE)

Polyserial Correlation, 2-step est. = 0.2558 (0.01231)
Test of bivariate normality: Chisquare = 9924, df = 5, p = 0

polyserial(segdata$IDT000003, segdata$CA0000801,ML = TRUE, std.err = TRUE)

Polyserial Correlation, ML est. = 0.2581 (0.01272)
Test of bivariate normality: Chisquare = 9720, df = 5, p = 0

                 1
Threshold -1.76500
Std.Err.   0.01041
```

I want to know what the difference between TRUE and FALSE in ML and std.err means. I can't know in the help(polyserial). Explanations are poor...

I would appreciate your interpretation of the result.

Comment: I know almost nothing about the topic, but [this polycor package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor/polycor.pdf) says of `ML`: "if TRUE, compute maximum-likelihood estimates; if FALSE, compute quick two-step estimates." Of `std.err` it says: if TRUE, compute standard errors.

Comment: @David / I know that. In this case, I want to know when I have to use ML=TRUE, FALSE & std.err=TRUE, FALSE...  Thanks you David for your reply.

Comment: Presumably, `ML = TRUE` uses maximum-likelihood estimates to compute the correlation coefficients, and `ML = FALSE` uses a coarser two-step method. I would expect better results from `ML = TRUE`. Beyond this, it sounds like this is really a question about statistics and methods. You might try this question on [Stack Overflow Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) if your question is more about these things than about the actual code.

Comment: You could also try [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), or you could add a `statistics` tag to your question here.

Comment: @David / wow! Thank you for your kind reply!! Have a good day David!